# ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: No such object

Tags: php, ldap

I successfully made a `ldap_connect()` but when I try `ldap_bind()` I'm getting the following message: `Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: No such object in /var/www/... on line 25`. What does this mean? I am doing something wrong or does the server has some configurations that prevent me to authenticate?

I am sure that the parameters for `ldap_bind()` are correct.

Comment: Show us the code? Because something is wrong if you have been presented with an error

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem meanwhile.
The code was something like this:

```
$ldaphost = "ldaps://XXX";
$ldapport = YY;

$ldaprdn="uid=username,ou=OU1,ou=OU2,ou=OU3,dc=dc1,dc=dc2,dc=dc3,dc=dc4";
$ldappass="password";

// Connecting to LDAP
$ldapconn = ldap_connect($ldaphost, $ldapport)
      or die("Could not connect to {$ldaphost}");

if ($ldapconn) {

    // binding to ldap server
    $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldaprdn, $ldappass);

    // verify binding
    if ($ldapbind) {
        echo "LDAP bind successful...";
    } else {
        echo "LDAP bind failed...";
    }

}
```

I was not setting the proper organisational units(ous). The `username`was in other ou. After setting the correct one everything was fine.